# How can I use SaveContactTask without exiting program in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When I use this task I can't do any thing in my application after saving the contact except showing a messagebox with a message how can I return again to my application when this task completed !!

Comment: Not sure I'm following... when you use the SaveContactTask you should be returned to your application after the task completes or the user canceled with the hardware Back button!

Answer (score 3):

This should work out the box. When task is finished your application takes control again. You can control task result using Completed event handler

```
this.saveContactTask.Completed += new EventHandler<SaveContactResult>(saveContactTask_Completed);

private void saveContactTask_Completed(object sender, SaveContactResult e)
{
    switch (e.TaskResult)
    {
        case TaskResult.OK:
        MessageBox.Show("Contact is successfully saved.");
        break;
        case TaskResult.Cancel:
        MessageBox.Show("The user canceled the task.");
        break;
        case TaskResult.None:
        MessageBox.Show("NO information regarding the task result is available.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Here you can find fully functional example which works exactly as you want. You may take a look and compare with your implementation

http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/8-How-to-use-SaveContactTask-in-Windows-Phone-Mango